# Jacobi Formula for determinants misconception?

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, partial-derivative, determinant, matrix-calculus

I am struggling to derive the Jacobi Formula for determinants using a method of my own:

Since $det(A)$ is a function of the elements of $(A_{ij})$, write
$$det(A)=F(A_{kr}); k,r=0,1,...,N$$
so the differential of the determinant is
$$ddet(A)=\sum_{kr}\frac{\partial det(A)}{\partial A_{kr}} dA_{kr} \tag{1}$$.
From the Laplacian Expansion of a determinant:
$$det(A)=\sum_{j}A_{ij}C^{ij} \tag{2}$$
where $C^{ij}$ is the cofactor in $A_{ij}$
Evaluating the partial derivative in (1) using (2):
$$ddet(A)=\sum_{jkr}\left[\frac{ \partial A_{ij}}{ \partial 
 A_{kr}}C^{ij}+A_{ij}\frac{\partial C^{ij}}{\partial A_{kr}}\right]dA_{kr}=\sum_{jkr}\left[\underbrace{\delta _i ^k}_{\text{since is fixed}}\delta _j^r C^{ij}+A_{ij}\frac{\partial C^{ij}}{\partial A_{kr}}\right]dA_{kr}$$
$$=\underbrace{\sum_{j}C^{ij}dA_{ij}}_{\text{leads to the Jacobi Formula}}+ \underbrace{\sum_{jkr}A_{ij}\frac{\partial C^{ij}}{\partial A_{kr}}dA_{kr}}_{\text{but this term is non-zero except for k=i or j=r?}} \tag{3}$$

---

However on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula the derivation using the Laplace Expansion involves:
$$\sum_{jr}\frac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial A_{ir}}C^{ij}+ \underbrace{\sum_{jr} A_{ij}\frac{\partial C^{ij}}{\partial A_{ir}}}_{\text{which is indeed zero}} \tag{4}$$

But doesn't the use of (3) assume that
$$ddet(A)=\sum_{j}\frac{\partial det(A)}{\partial A_{ij}}dA_{ij}$$
i.e. no sum over $i$ in which case the differential is incomplete?

What did do I wrong and why is my interpretation of the Wikipedia proof incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Recall what is $C^{ij}$. It is independent of $A_{ir}$ for all $r$, since it is an minor of the $i$th row.
More precisely,
$$
C^{ij}=G(\{X_{rt}\}_{r\neq i,t\neq j})
$$
for some polynomial function $G$ of $(n-1)^2$ variables.
So for all $i,j\leq n$,
$$
\frac{\partial C^{ij}}{\partial X_{ir}}=0,\qquad r=1,...,n.
$$

Comment: Sorry but my question is about $\sum_{jkr}A_{ij}\frac{\partial C^{ij}}{\partial A_{kr}}dA_{kr}$ in (3) being non-zero